# Legal meaning of as per and in accordance with

Tags: contract-law, salary

I am not legal expert and english is not my first language. I have to make some changes in a draft of legal document. I am not sure which sentence is correct. The situation is like "Mr. ABC visiting DEF institute for three months, but during this period of time his living cost and salary should come from main employer XYZ, and DEF is not responsible."

During this visit, Mr. ABC remains employed by XYZ, and he shall be paid full salary in accordance with the job contract with employer XYZ.

Vs

During this visit, Mr. ABC remains employed by XYZ, and he shall be paid full salary as per the job contract with employer XYZ.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a native English speaker, but not a lawyer. To me the two wordings seem to say the same thing. [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20per) along with other dictionaries defines "as per" to mean "in accordance with". "As per" is perhaps the more formal phrase and tends to get used in legal contexts, but there is nothing wrong with "in accordance with".